# How do I configure the default session for kate

Tags: configuration, session, kate

I am having some difficulty wrangling kate sessions.

I often have more than one instance of kate running. I use it for a lot of different things on different virtual desktops - all in the same activity - I only have one of those.

I usually start kate with the `-n` flag to start a new session.
I think I did this because it was starting a new tab in an existing instance of kate (on a different virtual desktop, etc.) if I didn't.

I know how to start kate with a saved session which has been customized for a particular purpose, but I can't seem to find where to do that for the default session.

My immediate need is that I want the default session to have all the plugins disabled. They're nice, but they waste screen real estate when I'm not using them.

I looked through all the config files I could find and I don't see anything that obviously relates to plugins.

I'm using kubuntu 18.04 on a notebook.

Comment: I don't use Kate's sessions. But have you looked at *View > Tool Views > Show Sidebars* and *Settings > Menubar* the settings below. You can strip away most of the stuff you don't want to see. I think you should be able to do so while keeping your plugins enabled.

Comment: Two problems: without sessions, you have to do that every time you open kate and the things I want to get rid often are search and replace, documents, and document switcher which are all plugins.

Comment: I just came here to ask this question and found my own question still unanswered. :(